# json_encode only works with JSON_PARTIAL_OUTPUT_ON_ERROR for Model with custom toArray

Tags: php, json, eloquent, laravel-5

I have an Eloquent Model, for which I created a custom `toArray()`-method, to include fields from a meta table (which I get by using the [eloquent-meta](https://github.com/phoenix-labs/eloquent-meta) plugin):

```
class User extends Model{

    // ... Other stuff
    public function toArray(){
        return array_merge(parent::toArray(), $this->getAllMeta()->toArray());
    }
}
```

When I now try to send this model as a JSON response using `Response::json(...)`, I get:

> **UnexpectedValueException** in Response.php line 403: The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(),
>   "boolean" given.

I have traced the error to the [`JsonResponse.setData($data)`-method](https://github.com/illuminate/http/blob/master/JsonResponse.php#L49), in which the `json_encode`-call returns false. The `json_last_error()`-method returns `JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX` and the `json_last_error_msg()`-method returns `Syntax error`.

Using the debugger I stopped on the line below and evaluated the statement myself. As expected, it does not work, however if I call it like this, it works:

```
json_encode($data, JSON_PARTIAL_OUTPUT_ON_ERROR);
```

This returns the complete, valid JSON that I expect, without any missing or NULL values.

What's even stranger is, if I stop in the `toArray()`-method and supply the merged array to `json_encode`, it works fine, even without partial.

Am I overlooking something obvious here??

Comment: So Model already implements JsonSerializable, and the jsonSerialize() is just a simple wrapper around its toArray(). Are you supplying the merged array directly, or are you doing `json_encode($mymodel->toArray())`?

Comment: @JoshfromQaribou no, I'm supplying the model directly. The funny part is, that it works fine, if I remove the `toArray()`-method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with the [eloquent-meta](https://github.com/phoenix-labs/eloquent-meta) plugin I used. Here's the relevant part from [my issue](https://github.com/phoenix-labs/eloquent-meta/issues/10):

> I traced the error back to the
>   [`Helpers.maybeDecode($value)`-method](https://github.com/phoenix-labs/eloquent-meta/blob/master/src/Phoenix/EloquentMeta/Helpers.php#L19):
>
> The current implementation tries to parse the value with
>   `json_decode($value)` and checks, whether that worked, by checking the
>   `json_last_error()`-function. The problem is, that this doesn't reset
>   the last error.
>
> When the `Helpers.maybeDecode($value)`-method is called, *while*
>   Laravel is *encoding* the model, and the value it tried to *decode*
>   was **not** an valid json (for example, a simple string), the error
>   code is set, causing the `json_encode()`-function to see it and return
>   `null`. The problem is with the global nature of the error-variable.
>
> My proposed workaround for this is to reset the
>   `json_last_error()`-function after checking if decoing worked, and the
>   only way I have found to do this is by decoding something valid (even
>   if it's just an empty array).

Here is the [Pull Request](https://github.com/phoenix-labs/eloquent-meta/pull/11) with the fix.